# should string parameters be promoted into a super-type?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am passing around different connection strings through parameters into methods of different objects:

```
public ConnectOrDie(string connectionString)
{
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                this._logger.ConfigurationNotFound();
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Configuration string is not found.");
            }

}
```

In order to support the DRY principal and not have to check `string.IsNullOrEmpty` *every time a method gets called*, **would it be considered good practice to create a type for it, and check it for validity in a centralized location?**

```
public class ConnectionString
{
   private string _value;
   public ConnectionString(string value)
  {
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) throw;
     _value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think so, i'm very favorable to `Semantic Types`, the only problem is that in c# you had to write a lot of boiler plate code for struct (that best fit in general with `Semantic Types`).

Comment: "boiler plate code for struct " --- can you explain please?

Comment: Overrides `Equals`, `GetHashCode` implement `IEquatable` etc. Even with a `class` you want [Structural Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) in this case.

Comment: i see !! could you recommend a source for where to get these boiler plate code samples?

Comment: Your question as it stands (the question in bold) is going to elicit primarily opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
struct ConnectionString : IEquatable<ConnectionString>
{
    readonly string _value;

    public string Value { get { return _value; } }

    public ConnectionString(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(value);
        }

        _value = value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj is ConnectionString && Equals((ConnectionString)obj));
    }

    public bool Equals(ConnectionString other)
    {
        return this == other;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ConnectionString left, ConnectionString right)
    {
        return left._value == right._value;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ConnectionString left, ConnectionString right)
    {
        return left._value != right._value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public static implicit operator ConnectionString(string value)
    {
        return new ConnectionString(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator string(ConnectionString value)
    {
        return value._value;
    }
}
```

You can call your method like this: `ConnectOrDie("conn");`

Comment: why did you use a struct instead of a class?

Comment: To avoid extra allocation.

Comment: thank you very much. would you recommend doing the same exact thing with Guid?

Comment: No because `Guid` it's by itself a defined type. Another example can be `Path` that we represent with a string normally.

Comment: but i am checking all over the place to make sure Guid (which for us is patient guid) is not null,. i want to centralize this check into a class

Comment: what do you say alex?

Comment: `Guid` is a `struct` cannot be null. You cannot avoid argument validation all the time, my point was that is a valid option to define a specific type (like for a connection string or a file path), and as a plus you can centralize validation.

Comment: really appreciate your feedback. i've decided to create a PatientGuid class since i had to validate for empty or null guids all over my methods. you say that it can't be null but "Guid?" can indeed be null